# ML Lemma problem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, integral-inequality

Denote by $Γ$ the circular arc {$z ∈ C : |z| = 3,\quad 0 ≤ Arg(z) ≤ \frac{π}{2}$} described in the
anticlockwise direction. Consider the principal branch of $z^1/2$. Using the ML lemma, without evaluating the integral, show that $$\left|\int_{Γ}\frac{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{z^2 + 1}dz\right|≤\frac{3√3π}{16}$$
I have an idea of what the ML lemma is and how to use it but I'm having some difficulty showing this one.

Answer (score 1):

For $z\in\Gamma$:
$$9=|z^2|=|z^2+1-1|\le|z^2+1|+1$$
So $\frac{1}{|z^2+1|}\le \frac{1}{8}$. Thus:
$$\left|\frac{z^{1/2}}{z^2+1}\right|\le\frac{\sqrt 3}{8}$$

And by the M_L lemma:
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma}\frac{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{z^2 + 1}dz\right|\le \frac{\sqrt 3}{8}l(\Gamma)=\frac{\sqrt 3}{8}\frac{3\pi}{2}=\frac{3\pi\sqrt 3}{16}$$

Answer (score 0):

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma for the ML-Lemma. Try now to show the inequalitiy.